# Where can I find a list of Shonen Jump issues which also lists what series was printed?

Tags: resources, shonen-jump

In [Ixrec's Guide to Japanese](https://web.archive.org/web/20171105092420/https://amaterasu.tindabox.net/guide/), I have been looking at learning to read Japanese. It says that after learning the alphabet, I should get a dictionary, some kind of source material, and a translation for it.

While the guide included source material dissections, I want to start getting source material myself for when I run out of what's in the guide. One of the points about getting source material is that

> above all else, you should enjoy reading the translated version

and below that suggest series serialized in the *Shonen Jump* magazines. Since of course, I want to avoid scanlations which could be inaccurate, I figured I should aim for series I know have been officially released in English. Three series that come to mind are *Naruto*, *One Piece*, and *Bleach*.

All I know of *Shonen Jump*, apart from the target demographic, is that weekly issues have 1 chapter of a series serialized in them while tankōbon compiles these chapters (though I could be wrong).

I am wondering if there is a site where I can look up what chapters were serialized in what issue of *Shonen Jump* to then match magazine issues to English tankōbon.

NOTE: the reason why I want to get *Shonen Jump* magazines instead of Japanese tankōbon is because at first, I may only be on 1 or 2 chapters and I'm sure the magazines take less space than a book. Also, it'll be a good test with the rest of the magazine as to how much of it I can understand without needing a translation to confirm.

Comment: Do you want to actually buy a specific shounen magazine issue? Or do you just want to read the raws online? If it's the latter, you can go here http://online.mangaraw.net/ , if it's the former, then I don't really think you can get a list of which chapter is from which magazine issue. Crunchyroll keeps a table of contents list, but they just tell you whether it is in a certain issue and not what chapter it is specifically. http://www.crunchyroll.com/forumtopic-809337/weekly-shonen-jump-rankings?pg=0

Comment: @PeterRaeves actually buy them, the problem with reading them online is that **i need a net connection** which i don't have all the time. ie. during lunch i may want to do some learning, there's no internet at work in the lunch break area so i can't read online there. also there having to fit my reading to when the site doesn't go down which on the internet could be at any time

Comment: If you want to buy specific issues, I think you might be best of asking Shounen Jump yourself.

Answer (score 1):

**[Jajanken - Weekly Shonen Jump Lab](https://www.jajanken.net/en/) provides a database of series published in the magazine.**

As far as I have seen, it allows:

- Browsing [per issue](https://www.jajanken.net/en/years) to see which serieses and chapters are published, and
- Browsing/searching per series to see which issues and chapters they are published

  - [*Naruto*](https://www.jajanken.net/en/sakuhins/QvL0BVl0NV)
  - [*One Piece*](https://www.jajanken.net/en/sakuhins/aAg89lnKZQ)
  - [*Bleach*](https://www.jajanken.net/en/sakuhins/Qv1nJDx0jK)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see the cover and the list of comics which were serialized in the current issue, you could use "Comicvine" website, it has a huge collection of covers for certain manga (JP) and comic (US) books

[Shounen Jump Latest Issue](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/weekly-shonen-jump/4050-43519/)

Preview of the website.

Issue List

[image]

Issue Details

[image]